# Getting syntax error in GLSL array constructor not supported

Tags: glsl

with this code

```
        var mat_add = gpu.createKernel(function(A, B) {
            var sum = [];
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
                sum.push(A[this.thread.y][i] + B[i][this.thread.x]);
            }
            return sum;
        }).dimensions([2, 2]);
```

I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred compiling the shaders: ERROR: 0:141: '' : array size must be greater than zero 
ERROR: 0:141: '[]' : array constructor supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only  
ERROR: 0:141: 'constructor' : array constructor needs one argument per array element 
ERROR: 0:141: '=' : Invalid operation for arrays 
ERROR: 0:141: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const array[1] of float' to 'highp float'
ERROR: 0:145: 'sum' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:145: '' : methods supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only  
ERROR: 0:145: 'push' : invalid method
```

This actually works:

```
        var mat_mult = gpu.createKernel(function(A, B) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
                sum += A[this.thread.y][i] * B[i][this.thread.x];
            }
            return sum;
        }).dimensions([2, 1]);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the GLSL? `var` is not a valid GLSL construct.

Comment: It's JavaScript compiled to glsl

Comment: Then until you post the actually GLSL that this compiles into, it's still *JavaScript*. And thus, your question is about JavaScript, perhaps with some reference to whatever tool you're using to compile it into GLSL.

Comment: Its ok now, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

i created python code to convert list into function getters : https://github.com/MhadhbiXissam/GLSL_LIST